# Not getting notifications from LocalNotification.fireDate

Tags: swift, localnotification

Why doesn't it show a notification after the button has been pressed?

If the fireDate was `NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 10)` it would work fine

How can i get notifications from an array?

```
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    var stringDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(timePicker.date)
    alarmArray.append(stringDate)

    let fixedAlarmArray = alarmArray
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(fixedAlarmArray, forKey: "alarmArray")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()


    //Local Notification
    var localNotification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    localNotification.alertAction = "Go to app"
    localNotification.alertBody = "Its Time!"
    localNotification.fireDate = timePicker.date
    localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)

    self.view.endEditing(true)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The date specified in fireDate is interpreted according to the value
>   of this property. If you specify nil (the default), the fire date is
>   interpreted as an absolute GMT time, which is suitable for cases such
>   as countdown timers. If you assign a valid NSTimeZone object to this
>   property, the fire date is interpreted as a wall-clock time that is
>   automatically adjusted when there are changes in time zones; an
>   example suitable for this case is an an alarm clock.

```
localNotification.fireDate = timePicker.date
localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
// the problem is here, you are setting the timezone after inputing your date
```

you should use localtimeZone and set it before setting the fireDate

```
localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
localNotification.fireDate = timePicker.date
```

Note:

> In iOS 8 and later, apps that use either local or remote notifications
>   must register the types of notifications they intend to deliver. The
>   system then gives the user the ability to limit the types of
>   notifications your app displays. The system does not badge icons,
>   display alert messages, or play alert sounds if any of these
>   notification types are not enabled for your app, even if they are
>   specified in the notification payload.

do like this:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound | UIUserNotificationType.Alert, categories: nil))
```

create an extension to combine the time picked with 0 seconds as follow:

```
extension NSDate {

    var day:            Int { return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay,           fromDate: self).day           }
    var month:          Int { return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMonth,         fromDate: self).month         }
    var year:           Int { return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear,          fromDate: self).year          }
    var minute:         Int { return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMinute,        fromDate: self).minute }
    var hour:           Int { return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitHour,          fromDate: self).hour   }

    var fireDate: NSDate {
        return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateWithEra(1, year: year, month: month, day: day, hour: hour, minute: minute, second: 0, nanosecond: 0)!
    }
}
```

then just use it as follow:

```
localNotification.fireDate = timePicker.date.fireDate
```

Comment: The notification types are already registered and the date picker mode is set to Time not date. It does work if the fireDate was set to a certain interval but doesn't when using a time picker. The question is how do i use it with the time picker correctly.

Comment: I have updated the answer. The problem is that you are setting the time zone after setting the fireDate.

Comment: It actually didn't make a difference, but i did realise that i do get notifications just not at the exact minute, seconds later depending on the second that i accessed the time picker it will start counting from that second.

Comment: It will pick the actual local time seconds for sure. You can combine the date picker time with a custom time if you need.

Comment: If the time was 10:15:30 PM when i accessed the time picker and i set the alarm for 10:16 pm, it will notify me at 10:16:30 PM. I want it to notify me as soon as it hits 10:16 PM not the time that i accessed the time picker.

Comment: I have updated my answer, it will probably solve your problem now.